# How can I show dynamic product data on a React JS detail page using PHP?

Tags: reactjs, api, dynamic, product

```
I have been try to creating dynamic click to detail page. But I forced a problem which is I can      not show the data when I click on a product on product page. below is my code in product detail page:
```

please help me to can be show the data to product deatail page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.